# en la pagina los nombres de las pestañas y el contenido dentro de estas se cargan desde la base pero no se hacer que los datos se muestren a la vez

Tags: javascript, html, sql, controller, vanilla

este es el condigo js del controlador de la pagina m_personal.html y se supone que al clikear las pestañas con los nombre  de los cargos va a salir informacion respeto al personal al que estos fueron asignados

```
const API_PERSO = SERVER + 'dashboard/usuarios.php?action=';

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {

M.Sidenav.init(document.querySelectorAll('.sidenav'));
M.Tabs.init(document.querySelector('.tabs',{
  swipeable:true,
}));
});
readRows(API_CARGO);
```

esta funcion debe funcionar con API_CARGOS

```
function fillTable(dataset) {
let content = '';

dataset.map(function (row) {
  
  content += `
  <li class="tab col s3 m3 l2"><a href="#${row.id_cargo}">${row.nombre_cargo}</a></li>
  `;
});

 document.getElementById('tabs-swipe-demo').innerHTML = content;


}
readRows(API_PERSO);
```

esta debe funcionar con API_PERSO

```
function fillTable(dataset) {
let content = '';

dataset.map(function (row) {
    
    content += `
    <div id="#${row.id_cargo}" class="col s12">
        <tr>
            <td>${row.nombre}</td>
            <td>${row.usuario}</td>
            <td>${row.dui}</td>
            <td>${row.telefono}</td>
            <td>
                <a onclick="openUpdate(${row.id_personal})" class="btn-floating blue tooltipped" data-tooltip="Actualizar">
                    <i class="material-icons">mode_edit</i>
                </a>
                <a onclick="openDelete(${row.id_personal})" class="btn-floating red tooltipped" data-tooltip="Eliminar">
                    <i class="material-icons">delete</i>
                </a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        </div>
    `;
});

document.getElementById('perso').innerHTML = content;

M.Materialbox.init(document.querySelectorAll('.materialboxed'));

M.Tooltip.init(document.querySelectorAll('.tooltipped'));
}

function openReport() {
  
  let url = SERVER + 'Reportes/personal.php';
  
  window.open(url);
  }
```

no se si tendria que mandar algun oro archivo para que puedan ayudarme, estoy trabajando con vanilla js

Comment: y cual es el problema que tenes?

Comment: que no logro que el nombre de las pestañas cargue cuando logro que que el contenido de estas si lo hace y viceversa, entonces mi idea fue mandar a traer a la variable donde esta el enlace de la api de cargos pero el contenido tinen qu eser llamado por el id de las pestañas el cual es el mismo id_cargo proporsionado por la base